# simple membership provider with active directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-5, membership-provider

I want to configure the simple membership provider with active directory for my project in MVC5.

The rough workflow will be as follows:

1. user navigates to the website.
2. website aquires users AD login name.
3. website logs user in via simple membership provider.

Please give some idea or link to work with this.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082807/mvc-4-authentication-with-activ-directory-or-membership-database

Comment: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity and http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx